# Book about a man abducted by aliens - from a boat in mid-ocean

Tags: story-identification

I read this book around 10 years ago. It is about a man who is abducted by aliens while on a boat in the middle of the ocean. He becomes a slave and then a  mercenary for the said aliens.

Another thing I remember is that the other character was a human-like looking alien woman that the main character falls in love with

Another scene I remember from the first chapter or so is when he wakes up he is shocked as he is in a cell with group of different aliens and he can understand them as had an operation and speech translator inserted in his throat.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Can you remember any more details about the characters, what kind of aliens they were, any specific things they said or did?

Comment: I know its vague but that's is what I remember as it was long time ago. Other thing I remember is that the other character was a human like looking alien woman that the main character falls in live with (I know typical). Other scene I remember from the first chapter or so is when he wakes up he is shocked as he is in a cell with group of different aliens and he can understand them as had an operation and speech translator inserted in his throat. That is all I am afraid Richard!

Answer (score 3):

I think the book you are looking for is "Hunters of the Red Moon" by "Marion Zimmer Bradley" and her brother "Paul Edwin Zimmer" . The "Hero" is Dane Marsh and is kidnapped off of his boat .The kidnappers are the feline "Mekhar" and they are slavers ,as mentioned they install a translator in he's throat .He and others are sold to the "Hunters" an unseen race ,the slaves are formed into groups and allowed to train . They are then taken to the Red Moon and are hunted.
   Hope this helps ,as a side note there is also a sequel called "The Survivors" 
Happy Hunting

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can revisit the book!!